# undefined method `image' for Album

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to display photos in an album.

This is the error that I receive (image below):
[image]

These are the current specs so far:

**Album Model**

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
end
```

**Photo Model**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :image, attachment_presence: true
  
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

**Photo Controller**

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @photo = @album.photos.create(photo_params)
        redirect_to album_path(@album)
    end

    def destroy
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @photo = @album.photos(params[:id])
        @photo.destroy
        redirect_to album_path(@album)
    end

    private 

        def photo_params
            params.require(:photo).permit(:name,:image)
        end
end
```

**View Folder - Photos/_photos.html.erb - where the error is generated from**

```
<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= photo.name %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= image_tag @album.image.url(:medium) %>
</p>
```

How do I fix this error?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
<%= image_tag @album.image.url(:medium) %>
```

try this

```
 <%= image_tag photo.image.url(:medium) %>
```

Comment: that works ... answer will be accepted in 6 minutes =) ... can you explain why I needed to do that instead of my original answer, please? Thank you.

Comment: Because your `image` attribute is located in `photos` table, not in `albums`.

Comment: and why did I not need to make make `photo` instance variable? ie. `@photo`?

Comment: `photo` enough because you render your photos in partial. It is same as render your `photo.name`.

Comment: thank you! (blah blah added since "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length")